# Set content container to 100% of body not parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, liquid-layout

I am trying to create a 2 column liquid layout with a menu on the left and site content on the right.

The menu is meant to go into the right column (`div.liquid-right`) and site content is then meant to go in to the left column (`div.liquid-left`).

I need the content container to be the same size as the body (that is, `div.liquid-right`) and not its parent which is the left container(`div.liquid-left`).

The layout can be represented by the following diagram:

```
_______________
|  ____     R |
| |L __|_____ |
| | |C |     ||
| | |  |     ||
| | |  |     ||    
|_|_|__|_____||
```

**HTML markup**

```
 <div class="liquid">
     <div class="liquid-right">
         <div class="liquid-left">
             <div class="content">
                 <div>main content</div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS style**

```
.liquid{
    width:100%; height:100%;  float:left;
}

.liquid .liquid-right{
    width:100%; float:left; background-color:#FFF; margin-top:45px;
}

.liquid .liquid-left{
    width:182px; float:left; min-height:200px; 
    background-color:#FF7575;  position:relative;
}   

.liquid .content{
    background-color:#00F; float:left;  height:100px; width:100%;
}
```

Currently the `.content` container is only the size of the left container (which is expected) but I have no idea how to expand it to the size of the body container.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4tK/

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do.  Please review your edited post to make sure it is accurate.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarcAudet you should'nt have bothered, I don't think anyone is going to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two content blocks inside of `left`. If you want them to expand, and keep `left` static, move those children out.

```
<div class="liquid-right">
   <div class="liquid-left">Left</div>
   <div class="liquid-content">Liquid Content
      <div>
         main content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhCke/

Comment: This is not what I want, the right will expand on its own if more content is added.

Comment: I didn't add some of these classes but I'll remove them and post a jfiddle link

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. My opinion is still the same (especially, for a fluid layout). You can cheat the parent width, by setting it's `overflow` to visible; however, when you then add `100%` as the child's width you are setting it to "be the parent's width" not the grand-parent's width.

Comment: Updated your fiddle. Removed the floats, and added positioning, as well as, overflow:visible to 'left' which will allow the width to cheat the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4tK/1/

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use `overflow:visible` to allow 'main' to cheat, all the other children of 'left' can cheat the width also. So you'll need to give them a max-width of 182px to match their parent.

Comment: The problem now is that the height of the layout does not expand with the content http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4tK/2/

Comment: You want to have your cake, and eat it too? :-) You can accomplish that only if you pay attention to the height of 'left', which isn't a fluid design approach. **http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4tK/3/**  So back to my original comment -- change your design pattern, and get 'main' out of 'left'.